# GmapsFX. Remove debug panel from map

Tags: java, google-maps, javafx

I've created a simple JavaFX project with Google maps using [GmapsFX](https://github.com/rterp/GMapsFX) 1.1.0

```js
public class CorrectorClientMain extends Application implements MapComponentInitializedListener {
 protected GoogleMapView mapComponent;
    protected GoogleMap map;

    private Button btnZoomIn;
    private Button btnZoomOut;
    private Label lblZoom;
    private Label lblCenter;
    private Label lblClick;
    private ComboBox<MapTypeIdEnum> mapTypeCombo;

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        mapComponent = new GoogleMapView();
        mapComponent.addMapInializedListener(this);
        BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
        ToolBar tb = new ToolBar();

        btnZoomIn = new Button("Zoom In");
        btnZoomIn.setOnAction(e -> {
            map.zoomProperty().set(map.getZoom() + 1);
        });
        btnZoomIn.setDisable(true);

        btnZoomOut = new Button("Zoom Out");
        btnZoomOut.setOnAction(e -> {
            map.zoomProperty().set(map.getZoom() - 1);
        });
        btnZoomOut.setDisable(true);

        lblZoom = new Label();
        lblCenter = new Label();
        lblClick = new Label();
        
        mapTypeCombo = new ComboBox<>();
        mapTypeCombo.setOnAction( e -> {
           map.setMapType(mapTypeCombo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() );
        });
        mapTypeCombo.setDisable(true);
        
        Button btnType = new Button("Map type");
        btnType.setOnAction(e -> {
            map.setMapType(MapTypeIdEnum.HYBRID);
        });
        tb.getItems().addAll(btnZoomIn, btnZoomOut, mapTypeCombo,
                new Label("Zoom: "), lblZoom,
                new Label("Center: "), lblCenter,
                new Label("Click: "), lblClick);

        bp.setTop(tb);
        bp.setCenter(mapComponent);
        bp.setLeft(btnType);
        Scene scene = new Scene(bp);
        
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public void mapInitialized() {
        //Once the map has been loaded by the Webview, initialize the map details.
        LatLong center = new LatLong(48.8539819,37.6144408);
        mapComponent.addMapInializedListener(() -> {
            // This call will fail unless the map is completely ready.
            //checkCenter(center);
        });
        
        MapOptions options = new MapOptions();
        options.center(center)
                .mapMarker(true)
                .zoom(12)
                .overviewMapControl(false)
                .panControl(false)
                .rotateControl(false)
                .scaleControl(true)
                .streetViewControl(false)
                .zoomControl(true)
                .mapType(MapTypeIdEnum.HYBRID);

        map = mapComponent.createMap(options);
                
    }

    private void checkCenter(LatLong center) {
         //
    }
    

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  launch(args);
 }
}
```

When I'm running the application I see the debug panel in the window:

[image: Firebug]

Can I remove this debug panel? Did I forget to set any parameters?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/oYKTA.png this is image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look at the project site, in the releases [link](https://github.com/rterp/GMapsFX/releases), there are two newer releases.

In fact, version 1.1.1 list of changes already addresses your problem:

> Fixed issue where FireBug plugin was always displaying by default with the Map.

So I suggest you update your version to the last one available [1.1.2](https://github.com/rterp/GMapsFX/releases/download/1.1.2-1/GMapsFX-1.1.2.jar).